# Express server deployed, not work in openshiftapps but works fine in local

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I just deployed my express.js server on openshiftapps and for some reason, one of the routes not working and I get :

> Internal Server Error

Same route is fine in local.this route is my root route which only should render my index.ejs file. the other routes working just fine. I share the codes here, I hope you guys can help to see where did I do wrong.

So this is my server.js code :

```
var express= require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var accountname = require('./routes/accountname');

var app = express();

//View Engine  (We Use ejs)

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'edaccounting')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api/v1/', accountname);

app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('Server is Started on port 8080');
})
```

And this is my index.js :

```
var express= require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
res.render('INDEX');   
})

module.exports = router;
```

so for this route : `app.use('/', index);` I get Internal server error on the real server but it's working in my local and render the .ejs file. Other route is fine in real server. I used openshiftapps and I build my node.js app there with no errors!

Comment: An internal server error is generally accompanied by an error being logged and a stack trace. Without those, it's going to be _really_ hard for people to debug your problem. Wild guess: your template file is called `index.ejs`, not `INDEX.ejs`

Comment: @robertklep I understand which is hard to debug, I wish I could give more info, but since it's working fine in local, can't debug in staging. well I change the name, also I try to use html instead of ejs by using app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); but no luck, still same error in staging.

Comment: You should check logfiles for errors.